# Adding list items using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, button

Please check my code. The code adds the list item but it suddenly disappears. Kindly let me know the error in my code.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="needButton">Need</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" id="haveButton" >Have</button>
      </form>
      <div class="myNeed">
        <ul class="need">
        <li>
          The needed items are
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
```

This is js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#needButton").click(function () {
    var needed = $("#bill").val();
    $(".need").append("<li>" + needed + "<li>");
  });
});
```

Comment: Change `<button type="submit"` to `<button type="button"`. Form is getting submitted currently.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because the button click triggers the form to be submit which redirects the page.

To fix this, hook your event handler to the `submit` event of the `form` element and call `preventDefault()` on the event. Using this methoid over change the `button` type means that users can still trigger the action by pressing the return key on the keyboard when the input has focus.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("form").on('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var needed = $("#bill").val();
    $(".need").append(`<li>${needed}</li>`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="bill" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" id="haveButton">Have</button>
</form>
<div class="myNeed">
  <ul class="need">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point #Accessibility  :)

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a typo you write id=haveButton but in js code you type #needButton try change that to #haveButton

Answer (score 0):

i did a simple  code for here i hop it will help you

```
<button id="add">Have</button>
<ul class="need"></ul>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#add").click(function () {
               var needed = '123.';
               $(".need").append("<li>" + needed + "</li>");
          });
     });
</script>
```